# How to get items under a hierarchy at a nested dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I've a dictionary comes from an infinite sub category tree structure. The example is below;

```python
    {
      "asset_id": 1566,
      "asset_name": "asset1",
      "asset_type": "A",
      "assets": [
        {
          "asset_id": 1255,
          "asset_name": "asset2",
          "asset_type": "A",
          "assets": [
            {
              "asset_id": 1472,
              "asset_name": "asset3",
              "asset_type": "A",
              "assets": []
            },
            {
              "asset_id": 1473,
              "asset_name": "asset4",
              "asset_type": "A",
              "assets": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "asset_id": 1257,
          "asset_name": "asset5",
          "asset_type": "A",
          "assets": []
        },
        {
          "asset_id": 1259,
          "asset_name": "asset6",
          "asset_type": "A",
          "assets": []
        },
        {
          "asset_id": 1493,
          "asset_name": "asset7",
          "asset_type": "A",
          "assets": []
        }
      ]
    }
```

I would like to get all items under a category on this tree structure.
For example, all assets under "asset_id"=1255.

Sample output;

```
[
        {
          "asset_id": 1472,
          "asset_name": "asset3",
          "asset_type": "A",
          "assets": []
        },
        {
          "asset_id": 1473,
          "asset_name": "asset4",
          "asset_type": "A",
          "assets": []
        }
      ]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Exactly what do you want to "get," and how exactly do you want it returned? (Do you want all "siblings" and their descendants of a key-value pair matching your input in the dictionary tree?) Showing the desired output from your example input would help but is not enough. Also, what attempts have you made on this problem so far, and just where are you stuck? Showing a code attempt from you would probably get you more answers.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to look up all asset objects that match a number of conditions specified in the form `key=value`, for instance `asset_id=1255`, then this might work for you.

```
def retrieve_assets(struct, **kwargs):
    def _rec(obj):
        if type(obj) is dict:
            if all(map(lambda k:obj.get(k) == kwargs.get(k), kwargs.keys())):
                return [obj]  #1
            else:
                return _rec(obj.get('assets'))  #2
        elif type(obj) is list:
            filtered = []
            for asset in obj:
                filtered.extend(_rec(asset))
            return filtered

    return _rec(struct)
```

You call it like:

```
retrieve_assets(tree, asset_id=1255)
```

It uses an inner function to recursively test all nested assets for satisfaction of the given conditions (passed as key-value pairs in the `kwargs` dictionary). If an asset satisfies those conditions, it gets returned to the caller in its entirety (`#1`, wrapped into a list). If not, the inner function recurses into testing the child asset list (`#2`).

Using the `**kwargs` named parameter expansion mechanism allows for the specification of lookup conditions with more than only the 'asset_id` field. You might as well issue a call looking like this:

```
retrieve_assets(tree, asset_type='B', assets=[])
```

That way, you'd get a list of all asset objects that are of `asset_type` `B` and don't have any children (that is, their `asset` list is empty) to themselves.

**Edit:** After my response, you made clear that you only want to retrieve those assets that are descendants of the asset which satisfies the specified condition. In order to achieve this with my solution, just change the line marked with the `#1` into:

```
return obj.get('assets')  #1
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, it does more than I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion:

```
d = {'asset_id': 1566, 'asset_name': 'asset1', 'asset_type': 'A', 'assets': [{'asset_id': 1255, 'asset_name': 'asset2', 'asset_type': 'A', 'assets': [{'asset_id': 1472, 'asset_name': 'asset3', 'asset_type': 'A', 'assets': []}, {'asset_id': 1473, 'asset_name': 'asset4', 'asset_type': 'A', 'assets': []}]}, {'asset_id': 1257, 'asset_name': 'asset5', 'asset_type': 'A', 'assets': []}, {'asset_id': 1259, 'asset_name': 'asset6', 'asset_type': 'A', 'assets': []}, {'asset_id': 1493, 'asset_name': 'asset7', 'asset_type': 'A', 'assets': []}]}
def get_assets(_d, below = 1255):
  if isinstance(_d, dict):
    if _d['asset_id'] == below:
      return _d['assets']
    _r = list(filter(None, [get_assets(i, below) for i in _d['assets']]))
    return _r[0] if _r else None
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(get_assets(d), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
 {
    "asset_id": 1472,
    "asset_name": "asset3",
    "asset_type": "A",
    "assets": []
 },
 {
    "asset_id": 1473,
    "asset_name": "asset4",
    "asset_type": "A",
    "assets": []
  }
]
```